# Запретить ботам переходить по определенным ссылкам

Tags: html, css, seo, поисковые-системы

Есть определенные ссылки, которые ведут на сайты продавцов. По этим переходам ведется статистика. Но боты тоже переходят по этим ссылкам. Как запретить им переходить по ним? `rel=nofollow` не актуален

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте этот вариант:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http:site.com/'; return false;">Текст ссылки</a>
```

Вместо ссылки можете использовать любой другой тег. При этом будет происходить переход, а поисковые роботы будут такую ссылку игнорировать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Почему rel=nofollow не актуален по вашему мнению?
2. Разместить через редирект на своём сайте и в нём уже вести учёт отбрасывая ip ботов
3. Вставить ссылки в блоке через JS

Comment: В вики написано что яндекс, гкгл, яху уже не смотрят на этот тег. Сейчас и так идет через редирект. Третий варриант хороший, не могли бы вы пример привести с ним?

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте использовать robots.txt и прописать в нем запрещенные для роботов ссылки

Пример содержимого (запрет перехода на /admin):

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /admin
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /admin
```

Файл должен находиться в корневой директории сайта